# VBA Code Sample to Look Up Multiple Criteria

Tags: vba

Am hoping I can get some help with a VBA code sample to look up specific values in multiple columns (4 to be exact) and populate a specific text in another column (outside of the first 4). This is all happening within 1 single worksheet. See below for 4 criteria and specified verbiage to be populated:

```
column 1 value: "Yes"
column 2 value: "Yes"
column 3 value: "R" or "S"
column 4 value: Begins with "9" or "88"
```

IF all criteria are met, then populate "AWP Review".

Answer (score 0):

I use my excel in spanish, but I'll try to translate the fomula
I guess you can write this formula to filter and copy and paste later

other way would be record a macro, filtering from left to right using your criteria

if I have a wrong idea let me know

=SI(SUMA(CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(A2,"YES",B2,"YES"),SI(O(C2="R",C2="S"),1,0),SI(O(D2=9,D2=88),1,0))=3,"SOME TEXT","")

=IF(SUM(COUNT.IFS(A2,"YES",B2,"YES"),IF(OR(C2="R",C2="S"),1,0),IF(OR(D2=9,D2=88),1,0))=3,"SOME TEXT","")

[image: THIS VALUES I USED]

Comment: Thank you! I think that you have the right idea, yes! However, I am looking for a dynamic VBA code I can use as opposed to a formula. Dynamic in a way that does what the formulas do and accounts for only looking at rows with data and not empty ones.